# Entity Framework + Azure, Database in a different time zone than the web app causing problems

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework, datetime, azure

I am running an MVC Core web app on an Azure App service with an instance of Azure SQL Server for the database.

I have changed the time zone of the App Service through the Azure Portal to be CEST, which is currently GMT+2.

The database is in Azure in Northern Europe, I don't know what the time zone is on the database, but it is most likely GMT or British Summer Time.

My dates are stored as simple datetime2 values, which means they have no TimeZone info. This means that whenever I do queries that compare dates on the database (and not in memory), the queries return incorrect results.

I am using Entity Framework Core (7) to query from the database.

An example of a query that is supposed to return past events, but does not include events from the last two hours:

```
private IOrderedQueryable<Event> GetPastEvents()
    {
        var result = _dbContext.Events
            .Where(t => t.DateTime < DateTime.Now)
            .OrderByDescending(e => e.DateTime);
        return result;
    }
```

What exactly is causing this?
What is the best way to deal with this?

Comment: Impossible to help without the application code and SQL queries. What is causing problems? Why would the database's *time* matter for stored values? Are you mixing local and UTC times perhaps in the application *and* the database? The real fix of course would be to use DateTimeOffset in the database *and* the application. Or store **only** UTC times and call UTC functions in SQL. Instead of `GETDATE()` use `GETUTCDATE()`

Comment: This is no different than the Unicode vs ANSI questions. The real solution is to use Unicode. The buggy workaround is to fix the codepage, knowing that this *will* break at one point or another.

Comment: Thank you for your reply, I have edited the question to hopefully be more clear.
My guess is that I am mixing UTC times and local times, yes, but I am clear on exactly how. My initial thought was that a quick fix would be to change the timezone of the database. Is that possible? Ideally I would store and work with UTC-times, but that means I have to change my datamodel, code and convert the data, so it would be preferable with a simpler workaround.

Comment: I don't think there is a quick fix. store all dates in UTC time on the DB, and anytime you need to show a local time to a user, do the conversion there, then convert back to UTC when saving.

Comment: @fiskeboss It's not the *database* that's causing the problem. It was caused when the data was saved. What *are* the dates stored in there? UTC or some local offset? Who saved them and what was the offset of *that* machine when it saved the data?

Comment: Furthermore, you are comparing them with *your* server's local time (DateTime.Now) instead of a UTC time (DateTime.UtcNow) or the database's local time  (`GETDATE()`). If the data was created as UTC, use UtcNow.

Comment: Finaqlly, you can emit use the database's date functions instead of passing your machine's time with [SqlFunctions.GetDate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.getdate(v=vs.110).aspx) and [SqlFunctions.GetUtcDate()](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.data.objects.sqlclient.sqlfunctions.getutcdate(v=vs.110).aspx). If the dates were generated by the database eg by a trigger or a default constraint, this can be the quick fix you look for.

Comment: When querying the data in SQL Management Studio, the date is returned like this: 2011-05-12 18:00:00.0000000. The date is output the same way in code. Is SQL Management Studio doing conversion from UTC, or is that the exact value that is stored in the table?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The fix was pretty straightforward; save the current time to memory before putting it into a Linq-to-entities query:

```
var now = DateTime.Now;
return _dbContext.Events.Where(t => t.DateTime < now)
```

My initial query produced an SQL query that used `GetDate()` in place of `DateTime.Now`, which of course evaluated to the current UTC time on the database.

Since my data is completely unaware of timezones, this works around the issue quite neatly.